# Reliability Probability problem

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probabilistic-method

What is the Probability that at least one close path is formed from $A$ to $B$ where  each switch has a probability of close $p$ and each switch is mutually independent of each other?

[image: Circuit]

**Proposed Solution**

Let event $A$ be such that

$$\begin{align}
A &= \{\text{Current Flows From A to B}\}  \\
&= \{ S_0^c  S_1^c  S_2^c  S_3^c, S_0^o  S_1^o S_2^c  S_3^c , S_0^c  S_1^o S_2^c S_3^c, S_0^o  S_1^c  S_2^c  S_3^c, S_0^c  S_1^c S_2^o S_3^c \} \\
\end{align}$$

where $S_0^c$ or $S_0^o$  shows the switch $S_0$ *Close* or *Open* respectively. Now the probability of $A$ is

$$\begin{align}
p[A] &= p^4 + p^2(1-p)^2 + p^3(1-p) + p^3(1-p) + p^3(1-p) \\
&= p^2(1+pq)\\
\end{align}$$

where  $q = 1-p$.

Comment: What is your question?  The final answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your answer.

$S_3$ must be closed regardless.

Then, the rest of the cases for which at least one of the paths connects are covered by the following:

- $S_2$ is closed; $S_0$ and $S_1$ have any other state (probability $p$)
- $S_0$ and $S_1$ closed, $S_2$ open (probability $p^2q$)

So the total probability is then $p(p + p^2q) = p^2(1+pq)$, which agrees with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, to calculate with the converse probability.

Probability, that the system ($S_0,S_1$ and $S_2$) doesn´t work: $(1-p^2) \cdot (1-p)$

So it works with the probabilty of $1-(1-p^2) \cdot (1-p)$

Thus, the whole system work with the probability of $(1-(1-p^2) \cdot (1-p))\cdot p=-p^4+p^3+p^2$

greetings,

calculus

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}
p[A] &= p^4 + p^2(1-p)^2 + p^3(1-p) + p^3(1-p) + p^3(1-p) \\
&= p^4+3p^3(1-p)+p^2(1-p)^2\\
&= -p^4+p^3+p^2
\end{align}$$

where  $q = 1-p$ and [$-p^4+p^3+p^2=p^2(1+pq)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%5E4%2B3p%5E3(1-p)%2Bp%5E2(1-p)%5E2) so as others nocited: your calculation for the event probability is correct.